# igraph R - 'error in base'

Tags: r, igraph

I've recently updated my Windows machine and reinstalled R3.4.0 (64bit) and igraph 1.0.1. I've previously used igraph in combination with FCMapper and it's worked perfectly.

On the new machine I keep getting the following error, even with code that previously worked without a hitch:

> Error in base::.Call("R_igraph_check_finally_stack", PACKAGE =
>   "igraph") :    "R_igraph_check_finally_stack" not available for
>   .Call() for package "igraph"
>
> Error in base::.Call(.NAME, ...) :    "R_igraph_finalizer" not
>   available for .Call() for package "igraph"

I've had a google and the previous responses indicate that it's a `NAMESPACE` error in the current version of the package. Any help would be appreciated!

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   Kingdom.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] igraph_1.0.1 FCMapper_1.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_3.4.0
>   magrittr_1.5   tools_3.4.0

Comment: Provide `sessionInfo()` result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: updated main post

Comment: Seems like a package bug. Please report in the bug tracker here: https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues  Make sure you add some reproducible example and include the necessary info about your system.

Comment: Thanks, I've raised it - https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/200 for anyone with the same issue